# How to return 5 topmost values from a list in R?

Tags: r, list, sorting

I've got a list of values which came from a `for` loop. I tried to sort them and find the top 5 values by `order(x,decreasing=TRUE)[1:5]`. But it came to the problem that "unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'".

So I decided to convert the list to vector by `as.vector(unlist(x))`, but it still tells me wrong with the list to `orderVector1`.

What should I do for that??

```
x

1. 705.171526014177
2. 397.876803328549
3. 540.043448992021
4. 663.541433109646
5. 962.376210043159
6. 442.670573166487
7. 296.736087125474
8. 757.852870690724

as.vector(unlist(x))
705.171526014177 397.876803328549 540.043448992021 663.541433109646 962.376210043159 442.670573166487 296.736087125474 757.852870690724

order(x,decreasing=TRUE)[1:5]


Error in order(a, decreasing = TRUE): unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

Traceback:

1. order(a, decreasing = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try - `head(sort(unlist(x), decreasing = T), 5)`

Comment: You didn't save your vector.

Comment: can you add `dput(x)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```r
myList <- list(705.171526014177, 397.876803328549, 540.043448992021,
               663.541433109646, 962.376210043159, 442.670573166487, 
               296.736087125474, 757.852870690724)

sort(unlist(myList), decreasing = T)[1:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to a `dataframe` or `tibble` and use `arrange` from the `dplyr`:

```r
x <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5))

x <- tibble(nums = x)

new_x <- x %>%
  arrange(desc(nums))

head(new_x$nums, 5)
```